# Shopify Get Filters from Sub Collections for Parent Collection

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I am trying to build a collection template in shopify that creates a collection template that can either be one collection or a list of collections, and if it is indeed a list, then of course I want all the filters to be listed from all the collections. I am using vue and that is the reason I need to convert this to javascript.

In shopify we cannot make sub collections, so on the admin everything is a collection.
I set up a structure of collections like this and the idea was to use this to form a hierarchy. Here there are three collections.

The important thing to note here is that `men-clothing-jeans` is a collection and has products in it, `men-clothing-shirts` is a collection and has products in it.
`men-clothing` is a collection and does NOT have products in it, it is empty and is a list for anything whose collection handle starts with `men-clothing-...`

```
|- men-clothing
  |- men-clothing-jeans
  |- men-clothing-shirts
```

Just to save time I will use the below example, I do have a code block that gets the above hierarchy off of the url and collection.handle, but for the sake of this example let's just use this liquid array below.

```js
// our array we will use
{% assign collectionHandles = 'men-clothing-jeans,men-clothing-shirts' | split: ',' %}

const collections = (() => {
  const collections = []
  let collection
  let product
  let products
  let filter
  let filters

  {% for collectionHandle in collectionHandles %}
    collection = {{ collections[collectionHandle] | json }}
  
    products = (() => {
      const products = []
      {% for product in collections[collectionHandle].products %}
        product = {{ product | json }}
        options_with_values = {{ product.options_with_values | json }}
        product.options_with_values = options_with_values
        products.push(product)
      {% endfor %}
      return products
    })();
    collection.products = products


    filters = (() => {
      const filters = []
      {% for filter in collections[collectionHandle].filters %}
        filter = {
          label: {{ filter.label | json }}
        }
        filters.push(filter)
      {% endfor %}
      return filters
    })();
    collection.filters = filters

    collections.push(collection)
  {% endfor %}
  
  return collections
})();
```

Now if we type `collections` in the console on the url: `some-example.com/men-clothing`, our products all work and come through thanks to this line

```js
{% for product in collections[collectionHandle].products %}
```

but the same does not work for the filters, they are empty even though we did the same thing for the filters.

the output looks like this:

```js
collections = [
  { handle: 'men-clothing-jeans, products: (2) [{..}, {..}], filters: [] },
  { handle: 'men-clothing-shirts, products: (1) [{..}], filters: [] }
]
```

If we navigate to the url: `some-example.com/men-clothing-jeans` now the filters object is working and the output looks like this:

```js
collections = [
  { handle: 'men-clothing-jeans, products: (2) [{...}, {...}], filters: (2) [{..},{..}] }
]
```

I can not figure out why this does not work because it works for the products but not for the filters. Filters can be accessed on a collection and we reference a specific collection by handle and the filters do not work unless you are on that specific collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In shopify the way things are set up, if you have a parent collection `men-clothing`, and a subcollection, `men-clothing-jeans`, the parent collection does indeed need to have all the products added to it, even if you don't plan on having a page that shows all the products. This seems silly but unfortunately it is a necessary step. All mens products would have to be added to 'men-clothing' collection, and then the child collections would work. In summary, you can't have a parent collection `men-clothing` and pull products into it from subcollections that you actually manually added products to from the shopify admin.